Why would wrapping a stored procedure invocation in another make a difference?
The SQL we've been executing for a while reads:
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[#SP_FOO_UPDATE]
AS
        BEGIN
        SET nocount ON
        EXEC [dbo].[foo_batch_sp] '20241002', 100
        END;
exec [dbo].[#SP_FOO_UPDATE]
;

Though it does seem dumb to wrap a stored-procedure call inside another like this, I don't see any reason for it not to work. And yet, is not working -- there are no errors, but the wrapped stored procedure is either not invoked, or is not doing anything, it is hard to say.
Yet, when invoked directly -- with the same argument -- the foo_batch_sp works as expected.
Things also work, if the two commands -- the CREATE PROCEDURE and the EXEC -- are submitted to the server separately, one after another (in the same session).
This discrepancy is the same whether the commands are sent from our program (via JDBC's preparedStatement()) or from a MS SQL GUI.
What could be the reason(s) for this? The server is Microsoft SQL Server 13.00.6445...

Why in the world would you do this, instead of just directly executing foo_batch_sp?

@KenWhite, I inherited this code from the Previous Administration. As I acknowledge in my question, I quite agree, that it is dumb. Yet, I still expected it to work -- and the question is: "Why does not it?"

You messed up your proc.  A stored procedure body contains all statements in the batch after AS.  The BEGIN ..  END pair has no effect.
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[#SP_FOO_UPDATE]
AS
        BEGIN
        SET nocount ON
        EXEC [dbo].[foo_batch_sp] '20241002', 100
        END;
exec [dbo].[#SP_FOO_UPDATE]  --THIS LINE IS IN THE PROC!!!
;

You must end the batch before running the proc.  In SSMS or SQLCMD you use GO for this.  In an App you run seperate command batches (eg JDBC statements*, or ADO.NET SqlCommands).  EG
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[#SP_FOO_UPDATE]
AS
BEGIN
   SET nocount ON
   EXEC [dbo].[foo_batch_sp] '20241002', 100
END;
GO
exec [dbo].[#SP_FOO_UPDATE]  

With dynamic SQL you can use a single batch, but define the proc in a nested batch.
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[#SP_FOO_UPDATE]
AS
BEGIN
   SET nocount ON
   EXEC [dbo].[foo_batch_sp] ''20241002'', 100
END;
'
exec sp_executesql @sql;

exec [dbo].[#SP_FOO_UPDATE] 

*a JDBC statement object is used to send a TSQL batch containing multiple TSQL statements.  JDBC is generic, and not all DBMSs have the same notions of statements and batches as SQL Server, so there's a confusing mismatch of terminology.

So, what would the proper syntax be?

See updated answer.

So, is it just the GO after the END;, that's missing, or does the indentation matter too?

Indentation is irrelevant.  But you can't use GO from your JDBC program. GO is not part of the TSQL language; it's a batch separator used by some admin tools like SSMS and SQLCMD.  You could use dynamic SQL to separate the batches, but using separate JDBC statements is simpler.

Your answer begins with "you messed up your proc". Can it be "unmessed", or there is no way to CREATE and EXEC the same stored procedure within the same batch?

Dynamic sql can do that.  See updated answer.

@DaleK, of course, an SP has to exist, before it can be called. This is why we're creating it first and then executing it. Or so we thought... Apparently, it must be created in a separate batch...

So, essentially, all SQL-statements following the CREATE PROCEDURE in the same batch are quietly assumed to be part of the procedure -- regardless of BEGIN and END encountered. Is that a valid summary, @DavidBrowne-Microsoft? Thanks!

That is correct.

From the documentation The CREATE PROCEDURE statement can't be combined with other Transact-SQL statements in a single batch.

Thanks. I wish, we got an actual error from the server -- instead of the trailing statements being quietly ignored :( Maybe, @DavidBrowne-Microsoft can effect a fix in future versions of the server?

Your non-working SQL was completely valid, and nothing was ignored, it just created a recursive SP i.e. an SP that called itself (in this case indefinitely), so there was no error to show you. SP's typically have multiple statements in them, hence why you can only have one per batch, because there is no other (easy) way to let the engine know where it ends.

As this is a temporary stored proc (prefixed #) I doubted the dynamic sql would work but it does. https://dbfiddle.uk/ieqLge3E (thought it would be auto dropped like a temp table)
